# How to get access from external config file to classpath in executing jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration, liquibase

I develop Spring Boot 2.2.1 application. I have multiple profiles (application-{provile}.yml) and use liquibase for migrate database automatically. Everything works almost fine (if it is possible to say that about Java, lol). But in production environment ***i have to pass config file as external yml file ourside from far***.

I am executing following shell to start application:

```
java.exe -jar orgstructure-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.profiles.active=prod -Dspring.config.location=./application-prod.yml
```

Application is starting and configs applies properly except liquibase. Liquibase use classpath for changelog configuration:

```
  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:db/changelog/changelog.xml
```

But changelog is inaccessible from external (outside of jar) application.yml therefore liquibase can not apply migrations. How to solve this issue and make liquibase to work in such environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution of this problem, i've separated applicatiom-prod.yml on two files on of them applicatiom-prod.yml is stored inside ./src/main/resources directory and it is packed inside jar, the second i called application-customization.yml and it is located separatedly from jar file but in same directory. application-prod.yml include seconds as follows:

```
  spring:
    profiles: 
      active: prod
      include:
        customization
    liquibase:
      change-log: classpath:db/changelog/changelog.xml

  logging:
    level:
      root: INFO
      org.springframework: INFO
      org.hibernate.SQL: INFO
      org.hibernate.type: INFO
      liquibase: INFO
```

Customization holds settings like database and authorization server connection and so on.